# BeautifulSoup XML Parsing - Only Return First Result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I am attempting to parse the following XML file using BeautifulSoup. However, only the first result is returned.

Given the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TransXChange>
    <StopPoints>     
        <AnnotatedStopPointRef>         
            <StopPointRef>StopPointRefOne</StopPointRef>
            <CommonName>CommonNameOne</CommonName>
            <Indicator>IndicatorOne</Indicator>
            <LocalityName>LocalityNameOne</LocalityName>
            <LocalityQualifier>LocalityQualifierOne</LocalityQualifier>
        </AnnotatedStopPointRef>
        <AnnotatedStopPointRef>  
            <StopPointRef>StopPointRefTwo</StopPointRef>
            <CommonName>CommonNameTwo</CommonName>
            <Indicator>IndicatorTwo</Indicator>
            <LocalityName>LocalityNameTwo</LocalityName>
            <LocalityQualifier>LocalityQualifierTwo</LocalityQualifier>
        </AnnotatedStopPointRef>
        <AnnotatedStopPointRef>          
            <StopPointRef>StopPointRefThree</StopPointRef>
            <CommonName>CommonNameThree</CommonName>
            <Indicator>IndicatorThree</Indicator>
            <LocalityName>LocalityNameThree</LocalityName>
            <LocalityQualifier>LocalityQualifierThree</LocalityQualifier>
        </AnnotatedStopPointRef>
```

And the following Python script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

inputFile = open("sample.xml","r")

contents = inputFile.read()

soup = bs(contents, 'xml')

StopPoints = soup.find_all('StopPoints')

for annotatedStopPointRef in StopPoints:
    print(annotatedStopPointRef.StopPointRef.string)
```

I only get the following result:
`StopPointRefOne`

Where I would expect:
`StopPointRefOneStopPointRefTwoStopPointRefThree`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, you are searching only for `'StopPoints'`, which there's only one. So the loop will iterate only once. You need to search also for `'AnnotatedStopPointRef'` inside the loop:

```
soup = bs(contents, 'xml')

StopPoints = soup.find_all('StopPoints')

for sp in StopPoints:
    for annotatedStopPointRef in sp.find_all('AnnotatedStopPointRef'):
        print(annotatedStopPointRef.StopPointRef.string)
```

Prints:

```
StopPointRefOne
StopPointRefTwo
StopPointRefThree
```